# ionic v6 webview 99 bug zoomed in certain samsung devices

Tags: android, ionic-framework, android-webview

So i've been stuck with the same problem for over a month now.
The problem is that on all pages the scaling ratio for the height isn't correct.
[image: photo bug]
There is a known bug in webview 99 on some samsung devices but there still is no fix.
I've got a company who all use the same model and they all have this bug.
As far as i know it happens on Samsung galaxy A12, galaxy A14 5G, galaxy S20..
Even chatgpt knew what was up lol so people have already talked about it.
[image: chatgpt answer]

I've also got the latest package versions of ionic

beneath my package.json with latest ionic version

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~13.2.2",
    "@angular/cdk": "~13.2.2",
    "@angular/common": "~13.2.2",
    "@angular/core": "~13.2.2",
    "@angular/fire": "^7.2.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~13.2.2",
    "@angular/material": "~13.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~13.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.2.2",
    "@angular/router": "~13.2.2",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/app-version": "^6.3.0",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/camera": "^6.3.0",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/firebase-x": "^6.3.0",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/keyboard": "^6.3.0",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/status-bar": "^6.3.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/mobile-accessibility": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/native-storage": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/network": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^6.6.0",
    "@ionic/cli": "^6.20.8",
    "@ionic/cordova-builders": "^7.0.0",
    "add": "2.0.6",
    "ionic4-auto-complete": "^2.9.9",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "ng-speed-test": "^2.2.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "swiper": "^8.4.5",
    "tslib": "^2.2.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
```

I've tried to use MobileAccessibility and set userPrererredTextZoom(false) but it didn't work.
I also can't eliminate which devices have the problem to temporary fix it with css.

there are like only 2 questions about it online, this is one :
https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/any-solution-for-zoom-problem-on-samsung-devices/227292

Answer (score 0):

i was able to fix it on the devices by providing a guide to change the screen zoom in the settings which by default is zoomed in a bit on these particular devices

[image: guide]